# Foursquare venue photo order

Tags: foursquare

I am doing a Foursquare query on venues and I need to get a list of photos.  I noticed that the photos in the array are ordered by the "createdAt" key.  Is there any part of the API that would return the photos in the order they are ranked in Foursquare, or at least get the top ranked photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, a [venues/photos](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/photos) call returns results in the order that they're ranked on Foursquare in order of "best."